# How is this returning "Given final block not properly padded"?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

This error only occurs sometimes, mostly with more complex passphrases, but even then, I'm printing the raw hex values of KEY, IV and CRYPTOGRAM in both encrypt and decrypt sides and they match! What am I not seeing? Is it the way i write/read from the file? (MAC is missing ik, it's the next step)

Encrypt :

```
private static String bytesToHex(byte[] hashInBytes) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();

}

public static byte[] sha256(byte[] text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] digest = md.digest(text);
        return digest;    
}
public static String aesCbc(String message, byte[] Key, byte[] iv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    try{
        IvParameterSpec Vetor = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec Chave = new SecretKeySpec(Key,"AES");

        Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cifra.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Chave, Vetor);

        byte[] cifrado = cifra.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cifrado);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Erro ao cifrar mensagem");
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    //USER IMPUT BEGIN
    System.out.println("Qual a pergunta?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String question = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Qual a resposta?");
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();
    answer = answer.toLowerCase();

    System.out.println("Escrever mensagem a enviar: ");
    String message = scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();
    //USER IMPUT END

    //GERAR NÚMERO ALEATÓRIO DE 128 BITS (16 BYTES)
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger randN = (new BigInteger(random.generateSeed(16))).abs();

    //CONCATENAÇÃO PASS+ALEATÓRIO
    byte[] randPassConcat = (answer+randN).getBytes();

    //CHAMADA DO MÉTODO DE HASHING
    int iteracoes = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis()-start<15000){
        try{
            randPassConcat = sha256(randPassConcat); 
            iteracoes++;                    
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Erro ao calcular hash");
        }                 
    }
    byte[] iv = random.generateSeed(16);

    String cripto = aesCbc(message,randPassConcat,iv);


    String key = bytesToHex(randPassConcat);
    System.out.println("KEY: "+key);

    //PRINT IV AS HEX
    System.out.println("IV: "+bytesToHex(iv));

    //PRINT CRIPTO AS HEX
    System.out.println("CRIPTO :"+bytesToHex(cripto.getBytes()) );

    String base64question = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(question.getBytes());
    //String base64cripto   = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cripto.getBytes());
    String base64iv       = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv);
    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt","UTF-8");
        writer.println(iteracoes); // NÚMERO ITERAÇÕES (int)
        writer.println(base64question); // PERGUNTA (string -> base64 string)
        writer.println(randN); // NÚMERO ALEATÓRIO (bigInt)
        writer.println(cripto); // CRIPTOGRAMA (string -> base64 string)
        writer.println(base64iv); // VECTOR INICIALIZAÇÃO (byte[] -> base64 string)
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Decrypt :

```
private static String bytesToHex(byte[] hashInBytes) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : hashInBytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return sb.toString();

}

public static String aesCbcDecrypt(String cripto, byte[] Key, byte[] iv) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec Vetor = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        SecretKeySpec Chave = new SecretKeySpec(Key, "AES");

        Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cifra.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Chave, Vetor);

        byte[] original = cifra.doFinal(cripto.getBytes()); 
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro ao decifrar mensagem");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static byte[] sha256(byte[] text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] digest = md.digest(text);
    return digest;    


public static void main(String [] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    //LER FICHEIRO LINHA-A-LINHA
    String array[] = new String[5];       
    try {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); //NOME DADO COMO PARÂMETRO
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
             array[i]=(scanner.nextLine());
             i++;         
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int iteracoes = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
    String question = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(array[1]));
    BigInteger randN = new BigInteger(array[2]);
    String cripto = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(array[3]));
    byte[] iv = (Base64.getDecoder().decode(array[4]));

    System.out.println(question);
    System.out.print("Introduzir resposta: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = scanner.nextLine();
    answer = answer.toLowerCase();
    scanner.close();

    byte[] randPassConcat = (answer+randN).getBytes();

    for(int i=0;i<iteracoes;i++){
        try {
            randPassConcat = sha256(randPassConcat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao calcular Hash");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String key = bytesToHex(randPassConcat);
    System.out.println("KEY: "+key);

    //PRINT IV AS HEX
    System.out.println("IV: "+bytesToHex(iv));

    //PRINT CRIPTO AS HEX
    System.out.println("CRIPTO :"+bytesToHex(array[3].getBytes()) );

    System.out.println(aesCbcDecrypt(cripto, randPassConcat, iv)); 
}
```

I know it looks like the wrong passphase but if the raw hex values match, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing binary data in the `String` variable `cripto` with

```
String cripto = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(array[3]));
```

And then later trying to get your binary data back from the String in this statement

```
byte[] original = cifra.doFinal(cripto.getBytes());
```

As there ain't a one-to-one translation of all bytes back and forth between `byte[]` and `String`, you end up corrupting the data, which in the end gives you the padding error. The padding error is just a symptom of the data being corrupted.

Just keep the data in a `byte[]` after your base64 decode